# In hibernate, how to make use of database time?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, date

I am using hibernate's timestamp method to update the last_modified value whenever my row in the table is updated. Like this:

```
<timestamp name="lastModified" column="last_modified" />
```

I am using postgres db. When Hibernate updates the row, does it fire an SQL with now() or the plan vanilla date?

The reason is that I want it to use now() so the dates are consistent as then, database will assign the value not the appserver.

Answer (score 2):

Using "timestamp" will make Hibernate use its idea of the current time, not the database's idea (this was correct as of Hibernate 3.0 and I doubt it's changed since).

If you want the column to receive database time, you can use a trigger to populate it on insert/update. If you want that generated time retrieved back by Hibernate, use a `generated="always"` or `generated="insert"` as appropriate (and demote the `timestamp` element to a normal `property`). Note this will produce additional select statements after update/inserts to retrieve the generated state.